# apply to/apply for/apply in

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct?

I am interested in applying **to** Master´s degree program in X

I am interested in applying **for** Master´s degree program in X

I am interested in applying **in** Master´s degree program in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of them are correct.

Acceptable phrasing would be:

> I am interested in applying to the Master´s degree program in X

You would use this if referring to a specific program at a specific University.

Also acceptable:

> I am interested in applying for a Master´s degree program in X

You might use this if you are talking about applying to some program but you don't know which University yet.

Answer (score 0):

You apply TO the institution for admission to the program. You do not apply to the program, you apply to the institution.

However, I also agree with northernman when he says

"I am interested in applying for a Master´s degree program in X

You might use this if you are talking about applying to some program but you don't know which University yet"